# How I can print only these revision I want?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to print out revision from 3 to 7 not all. Can someone explain how to do that?

```
          logEntries = repository.log(new String[] {""}, null,
               about.getStartRevision(), about.getEndRevision(), true, true);

   }

   for (Iterator entries = logEntries.iterator(); entries.hasNext();) {
       /*
        * gets a next SVNLogEntry
        */
       SVNLogEntry logEntry = (SVNLogEntry) entries.next();
       System.out.println("_________________________________________________________");
       /*
        * gets the revision number
        */
       System.out.println("Revision: " + logEntry.getRevision());
       /*
        * gets the author of the changes made in that revision
        */
       System.out.println("Author: " + logEntry.getAuthor());
```

Comment: If you only want revisions from 3 to 7, why don't you pass 3 and 7 as arguments to startRevision and endRevision?

Comment: I used but it only shows startRevision and don't stop at endRevision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the revision number is between 3 and 7 and if so then display.

```
for (Iterator entries = logEntries.iterator(); entries.hasNext();) {
   /*
    * gets a next SVNLogEntry
    */
    SVNLogEntry logEntry = (SVNLogEntry) entries.next();
    int revisionNumber = logEntry.getRevision();

    if(revisionNumber => 3 && revisionNumber <= 7) {

        System.out.println("____________________________________________________");
       /*
        * gets the revision number
        */
       System.out.println("Revision: " + revisionNumber);
       /*
        * gets the author of the changes made in that revision
        */
       System.out.println("Author: " + logEntry.getAuthor()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
logEntries = repository.log(new String[] {""}, null,
           about.getStartRevision(), about.getEndRevision(), true, true);

}

for (Iterator entries = logEntries.iterator(); entries.hasNext();) {
   /*
    * gets a next SVNLogEntry
    */
   SVNLogEntry logEntry = (SVNLogEntry) entries.next();
   System.out.println("_________________________________________________________");
   /*
    * gets the revision number
    */
   if(3<=logEntry.getRevision()&&logEntry.getRevision()<=7){
   System.out.println("Revision: " + logEntry.getRevision());
   }       
   /*
    * gets the author of the changes made in that revision
    */
   System.out.println("Author: " + logEntry.getAuthor());
```